# App crashes saying 'Unfortunately, app has stopped' while using asmack

Tags: xmpp, asmack

Here is my code for connecting to OpenFire through aSmack API. I am getting an error saying 'unfortunately app has stopped' when trying to run the app on my phone. When i remove the code of aSmack, the app is working fine with creating one button. I also have added the jars into the classpath. Please help me.

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.File;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String username = "swapnil", password = "swapnil", host = "192.168.0.4", service = "mirana";
int port = 5222;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final EditText et =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //  et.setText("Test");
            XMPPConnection xmpp = null;
            ConnectionConfiguration xmppConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration("192.168.0.4", 5222,"mirana");
            xmppConfig.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
            xmppConfig.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
            if (xmppConfig == null)
                throw new NullPointerException("XMPPService must be configured before it can connect!");
            try {
                if (xmpp == null) {
                    xmpp = new XMPPConnection(xmppConfig);
                }
                xmpp.connect();
            } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                et.setText("ERROR !");
            }


        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

And here is the manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.demo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.demo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you add logcat log?

Answer (score 0):

Without log, after watching your code,what I can guess is that, you are running smack methods on Main Thread.. The exception should be of `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

You should do the task, in your button click, on background threads. You might want to create `AsyncTask` for this.

Also, you dont have Internet permission. So please fix that too..

While implementing Smack, you need to take care of maintaining sessions of Smack Connections and related ones.. For this, you can refer the following the GitHub demo app: [Smack Android Demo](https://github.com/meisterfuu/SmackAndroidDemo)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `Internet` permission in your *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And you need to add below code in `onCreate()` method.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```